# Adding line of text between <div> tags

Tags: php, html, text

This is probably extremely simple, but all of my attempts so far have been failures.

Here is the PHP code prior to my edits:

```
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='watch_action'>";    
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='watch_position' style='float:".$alignment."; '>";
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='action_like' >".
```

I want to add in a simple line of text:

```
<span class="action-text">Please vote for the above article:</span>
```

I was told to put the < span > above "just before the div element having class as watch-position."

All of my attempts to place the < span > line in the PHP was a complete mess, resulting in errors. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Considering you are breaking out of the string to concatenate the variable anyway you should just use single quotes for your strings. It will reduce load times slightly and means you don't have to escape the double quotes you should be using on html attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='watch_action'>";  
$wti_like_post .= '<span class="action-text">Please vote for the above article:</span>';  
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='watch_position' style='float:".$alignment."; '>";
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='action_like' >".
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You probably failed to escape the double quotes inside the string, or change them for single quotes:

```
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='watch_action'>";
$wti_like_post .= "<span class='action-text'>Please vote for the above article:</span>";
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='watch_position' style='float:".$alignment."; '>";
$wti_like_post .= "<div id='action_like' >".
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks very much for commenting, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I prefer like that:

```
$wti_like_post .='<div id="watch_action">
<div id="watch_position" style="float:'.$alignment.'">
<span class="action-text">Please vote for the above article:</span>
<div id="action_like" >';
```

I changed double quotes for single one and use between they the normal html code.